# Count the duplicate value in the array list using php

Tags: php

I have an array in which I need to count duplicate values.

Here's the original array...

```
array(
    [0] => 23.07.2014
    [1] => 23.07.2014
    [2] => 23.07.2014
    [3] => 22.07.2014
    [4] => 22.07.2014
    [5] => 21.07.2014
    [6] => 21.07.2014
    [7] => 21.07.2014
    [8] => 20.07.2014
    [9] => 20.07.2014
    [10] => 19.07.2014
    [11] => 19.07.2014
    [12] => 18.07.2014
    [13] => 18.07.2014
    [14] => 18.07.2014
    [15] => 17.07.2014
    [16] => 17.07.2014
    [17] => 17.07.2014
    [18] => 16.07.2014
    [19] => 15.07.2014
    [20] => 14.07.2014
    [21] => 13.07.2014
    [22] => 13.07.2014
    [23] => 12.07.2014
    [24] => 12.07.2014
    [25] => 11.07.2014
    [26] => 11.07.2014
    [27] => 10.07.2014
    [28] => 09.07.2014
    [29] => 09.07.2014
    [30] => 08.07.2014
)
```

and I want to get a count of every value in the array, for example:

```
23.07.2014   Count=3
24.07.2014   Count=2
25 07.2014   Count=1
29.07.2014   Count=1
28.07.2014   Count=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$vals = array_count_values($array);

$key=array_keys($vals);
$value=array_values($vals);
$count=count($vals);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
echo  $key[$i]."=>".$value[$i]."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
 print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something likethis should work: (not tested)

```
unset($tempArr);
foreach ($arr as $elem => $content) {
    if(isset($tempArr[$content]) $tempArr[$content]++;
    else $tempArr[$content] = 0;
}

echo '<pre>'.print($tempArr).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by diffrent count of existing array count and unique array count...

```
`$duplicates = count($currentArray)-count(array_unique($currentArray));
 echo $duplicates;
```